# how to access item from python sql select

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to get a random row from a SQL SELECT query:

```
    SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tblQuestion'
    cursor = Databaseconnector.SELECT(SQL)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    rand = random.random(0,10)
    pprint.pprint(rows)

    row = rows(rand)
```

However, it complains that:

```
    Type Error: List object is not callable
```

on the final line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
row = random.choice(rows)
```

which will select a random element from the list `rows`.

Or check whether you can select directly a random row:

```
SELECT * FROM tblQuestion ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```